# How to make commits in another branch without checkout?

Tags: git

I have a git repository with an orphaned branch. I am currently on the `master` branch, and I have made a copy of the orphaned branch like like this:

```
git read-tree other-branch
git checkout-index -f -a --prefix=/home/user/another-workdir/
git read-tree master  # Restore
```

Suppose I make changes to the files in `/home/user/another-workdir/`, how do I commit those changes onto the orphaned branch without changing my current working directory (i.e. without `git checkout`)?

I tried `git --work-dir=/home/user/another-workdir/ commit -a`, but that affects the branch I am currenly working on (`master`).

Answer (score 1):

The *easiest* way, by far, is: don't.  That is, don't try to do this, this way, at all.  Do it another way.

If you have Git version 2.15 or later—or even 2.5 or later—you have a command, `git worktree`, with sub-commands.  One of the sub-commands is `git worktree add`.  This needs the name of another branch, e.g., `other-branch`, as an argument, and also the name of a place to create a new work-tree, in the other order:

```
git worktree add ../auxiliary other-branch
```

(assuming `../auxiliary` gets you to a place where Git can `mkdir auxiliary` outside of your existing work-tree; `/home/user/another-workdir/` is probably fine as well).

So: use `git worktree add` to create a *new* work-tree as shown here.  This new work-tree is all new, so there are no files that you could overwrite.  The new work-tree gets a new index, too, so that the index/work-tree pair that cover your main work-tree, the one where you're on branch `master`, is totally independent of the new index/work-tree pair for this other branch.

You can now start a new shell window, or `pushd ../auxiliary`, or whatever you like to get into the new work-tree that's on the independent branch.<sup>1</sup>  Here, you can copy the files from the main work-tree, `git add`, and `git commit`.  It's like having a separate repository, except that the commit goes into *the* (shared) repository, updating *the* (shared) branch name `other-branch` in the main repository automatically, with no separate `git fetch` step required.

If you have a Git that is >= 2.5 but < 2.15, finish all this work and then go back to the main repository within 14 days, and use `rm -rf ../auxiliary` (or wherever you stored the repository) and `git worktree prune`.  This will sidestep a nasty bug: these versions of Git fail to check for references in the added work-trees and can discard objects that are in use when running a `git gc` (from either work-tree!).  If your Git is 2.15 or later, the bug is fixed and there's no need to clean up, although you might want to anyway.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Orphan branch" is not a great term for this, as Git uses it specifically to talk about the setup in which you are on a branch name that does not exist, made by running `git checkout --orphan`.  That name ceases to be an "orphan" as soon as you commit from this state.  The `checkout` command calls it an *orphan branch* and `git status` calls it a *an unborn branch*, so Git itself is a little confused as to what the right term is.

In your case, though, the branch name `other-branch` *does* exist, and points to some existing commit.  It's just that the commit to which the branch name points, and all of its ancestors, lead back to a different root commit and not to a root commit shared with the tip commit of `master`.  So, "unrelated" might be a good term, or "independent" as I used here, or "differently-DAG-ged" to be a bit technical.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to Torek:  **Don't do this!**

For information's sake, it is possible to create commits on other branches, or anywhere in the tree using `git  write-tree`, `git commit-tree`, `git branch`, and possibly other commands depending on the operation you want to do.